# How to animate a fill with jQuery

Tags: jquery, svg

I was using

```
element.css('fill','#000000');
```

and it works, but now I want to animate a fill so I wrote this:

```
$(element).animate({'fill': '#000000'}, 'slow');
```

but this doesn't work, why? I would add, I am working on SVG file.

Comment: What are you expecting to animate? Are you looking for a fadeIn, filling from top to bottom, left to right, zebra stripes ?

Comment: Can you post your HTML or create a fiddle at [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: `fill` is the color of the element you're drawing, *not* the act of filling it up

Answer (score 20):

Specifying the transition as part of the CSS may be simpler than adding another js lib:

```
$('#circle').css({fill: "red", transition: "2.0s"});
```

Answer (score 4):

JQuery does not not support the animation of SVG elements, nor does JQuery UI. You can, however, use the [JQuery SVG](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html) plugin, and do the following.

```
$('#circle').animate({ svgFill: 'red' }, 4000);
```

<kbd>[Demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NZmC6/1/)</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

You may consider using jQuery-UI. Its .animate() function does not support animate the fill property by default. But as it uses the jQuery Color Plugin to animate colors, you can simply use jQuery.Color.hook() to allow additional css properties be animated. See [documentation](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/#example-use-1).

```
jQuery.Color.hook( "fill stroke" );
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4d8td/22/)