# How to animate svg stroke color?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have svg picture and I would like to animate stroke color:

I have tried this but nothing happen:

```
$(".svg-path").animate('stroke','blue')
```

It works when I set property directly without animating it:

```
$(".svg-path").attr('stroke','blue')
```

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: do you have the jquery color plugin?

Comment: yes, I do - version 2.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

I forgot to add hook to support other css properties:

```
jQuery.Color.hook( "stroke" );
```

Then

```
 $(".svg-path").animate({
    'stroke': 'blue'
 }, 200);
```

works pretty well!

Answer (score 0):

it also works like this:

```
$(".svgpath").animate({
    'stroke-width':'10',
    svgFill: 'red',
    svgStroke: 'green'
  }, 5000);
```

using **svgFill** and **svgStroke**

like in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NZmC6/2/)  using  *jquery.svg.js* and *jquery.svganim.js*  libs

Sources : already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21516595/how-to-animate-a-fill-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, quite convenient, is to specify the animation within the CSS, as so:

```
$(".svg-path").css({'stroke': 'blue', transition: "0.2s"});
```

I noticed you cannot use `.animate()` to change fill color, but `.css()` with `transition` works fine for fill color as well.