# Fade out after animating SVG fill color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I'm trying to do an animation of a simple svg checkbox.

```
<svg class="checkbox" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
   <circle class="circle" stroke="green" stroke-width="2" cx="26" cy="26" r="25" fill="transparent"/>
   <path stroke="green" stroke-width="5" fill="none" d="M14.1 27.2l7.1 7.2 16.7-16.8"/>
</svg>
```

This is a circle, with a checkbox inside it. I'm trying to animate the 'fill' property of the circle. [Searching stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25104648/1465472) tells me that

```
$('.circle').on("click", function() { 
    $(this).animate({fill : 'green'});
});
```

will not work because vanilla jQuery does not support animating `fill` for SVGs. However, the `css` function does work:

```
$('.circle').on("click", function() { 
  $(this).css({fill : 'green', transition: "2.0s"});
});
```

I want to fade the entire svg out after the animation is completed, but `css` has no callback! I'm forced to basically hack around the 2 second transition with the `delay` function:

```
$('.circle').on("click", function() { 
  $(this).css({fill : 'green', transition: "2.0s"});
  $(".checkbox").delay(2000).fadeOut('fast'); 
});
```

Is there any more graceful way to do this? I'm reluctant to include a new javascript library just for the purpose of fading this out elegantly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a more elegant approach using `transitionend`:

```js
function fillGreen() {
  $(this).css({fill : 'green', transition: "2.0s"});
}

function fadeoutCheckbox() {
  $(".checkbox").fadeOut('fast'); 
}

$('.circle')
  .one('click', fillGreen)
  .one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', fadeoutCheckbox);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg class="checkbox" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
   <circle class="circle" stroke="green" stroke-width="2" cx="26" cy="26" r="25" fill="transparent"/>
   <path stroke="green" stroke-width="5" fill="none" d="M14.1 27.2l7.1 7.2 16.7-16.8"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
$("#someSelector").one("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function(){ ... });
```

Gives you a call back when the transition end