# Detect end of JQuery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a working Jquery animation like this:

```
const e = $("#span-7");
e.css({fill: "#4287f5", transition: "0.5s"});
```

How can I detect the end of the animation?

I tried this with no luck!

```
e.one("animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd", function(){
       console.log('Animation Ended!');
});
```

Edit: Guys please, animate does not work for fill animation. I need to use .css animation.

Comment: what jquery version you are using?

Comment: `jquery-3.5.1.min.js` Does it matter?!

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery you can animate with `.animate()` method

.animate() method has [complete callback](https://api.jquery.com/animate/)

```
const e = $("#span-7");
e.animate({
  fill: "#4287f5"
}, 500, function(){
   // animation complete
})
```

**UPD: For animate fill property you must use jQuery plugin** [jQuery Color](https://code.jquery.com/color/)

Working demo https://codepen.io/-greg-/pen/jOqMJNp

**UPD: if you don't want use jQuery color plugin:**
Use event `transitionend` and `webkitTransitionEnd` [demo](https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_transitionend)

Comment: Your code doesn't work!!!

Comment: I mean  the animation not working..

Comment: The element is an SVG tspan

Comment: My script is working, you ask about callback, i give you answer about call back.
Other question how to animate fill property, you can chack it here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21516595/how-to-animate-a-fill-with-jquery/32406261#:~:text=animate()%20function%20does%20not,additional%20css%20properties%20be%20animated.)

Comment: Sorry but your script is not working... using `fill` inside animate won't work and that's why I'm using `.css` to animate the fill... my question was not about how to use a callback with`animate` that's what almost no one here could understand it properly...

Comment: It's working fine, check it https://codepen.io/-greg-/pen/jOqMJNp

Callback workig fine, you need read my link before about how to .animate() fill.

For animate fill add [jquery-color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) plugin its official plugin from jQuery 
[official page](https://code.jquery.com/color/)